# instafeed help required to work on website

Tags: javascript, instagram, instafeedjs

I am newbie to scripting and website designing. I am helping as well as getting hands on experience on my friends website. Earlier instafeed was working but since last couple of days its not showing any instafeed.

check the website. http://qminmagazine.com/

Please help me to figure out whats wrong.

Thanks in advance.
-Jitu.

Answer (score 0):

So, a simple network capture throws the following error:

*Error from Instagram: The access_token provided is invalid.*

On June 1st 2016, Instagram rolled out [new API restrictions](http://developers.instagram.com/post/133424514006/instagram-platform-update), which limits users to accessing only their own content through the Instagram API by forcing each app into a sandbox. To get access to public content, your app must be manually approved by Instagram.

Chek Instagram's update from the 17th of November 2015 :

> Instagram Platform and documentation update. Apps created on or after Nov 17, 2015 will start in Sandbox Mode and function on newly updated API rate-limits and behaviors. Prior to going Live, and being able to be used by people other than the developers of the app, these apps will have to go through a new review process. Please read the API documentation or the Change Log for more details.
>
> Any app created before Nov 17, 2015 will continue to function until June 2016. After June 2016, the application will automatically be moved to Sandbox Mode if it wasn't approved through the review process. The previous version of our documentation is still available here.

With the new rules, having Instagram tag feeds of public content isn't an acceptable use case, so even if you try to get your app approved, it most likely won't. So, with Instafeed you can only get your own posts, severely limiting its functionality.

This GitHub [discussion](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/408) delves deeper into the topic and available workarounds.

**How to submit for permissions review**

Go to Manage Clients and select the app you'd like to submit for Permissions Review 
Click the Permissions tab 
Click the Start Submission button 
Describe the purpose of your application and how you intend to use each permission

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Shubham.

Comment: Please upvote & mark and answer it it answers your question.